# what is firefox profileing and how can we change firefox profile using selenium webdriver

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, profiling

I have started to learn automation testing and i have come across this concept and its little difficult to understand. I am new to this concept. So..

what is Firefox profiling and how can we change Firefox profile using selenium web driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium WebDriver launch firefox with a default profile. If you want to launch firefox with your customized settings you can do so by using Firefox Profile.

For Example, if you want to add any extension to firefox you can simply use.

```
FirefoxProfile fp = new FirefoxProfile();
//fp.addExtension(extensionToInstall);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(fp); // here you can launch your webdriver with your customized firefox profile.
```

Another way to use firefox profile is given [here](http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/custom-firefox-profile/)